# Android: How to get ID_TOKEN using GoogleAuthUtils from a third-party module?

Tags: android, sdk, google-authentication

So, I am building an Android module that will be provided to android apps as a Gradle dependency (or AAR package). Eg. Just like Mixpanel, Google Analytics provide their modules to interact with their services, we will be providing our service's SDK to interact easily with our service.

I'll refer our module as SDK and the app in which it is included as Parent App.

For enhances user experience, we would like to fetch an ID_TOKEN of the user using the Parent App. But fetching an ID_TOKEN involves creating a Client ID in cloud.google.com using the SHA1 signature of the build key and the name of the package.

When someone would be including our SDK in their apps (Parent App), we cannot know what the SHA1 signature of their build key is and what the name of their package is.

I was wondering how we can achieve this. Or a better question: Is it something that can be done only if we ask in OUR OWN apps?

Thanks for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are referring to ID token for a Google account (i.e. sign in with Google).

First of all, GoogleAuthUtil.getToken was the legacy way of retrieving an ID token, which won't give you the best user experience. Check out this blog post for details:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/05/improving-security-and-user-experience.html

You should use Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API instead for ID token retrieval:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth#send-the-id-token-to-your-server

Second, if it's "Parent App" that requests a token, the app's identity will be "Parent App" to Google's OAuth backend, and you are right, no way you can masquerade the token retrieval as your app. (And it doesn't make sense if you could masquerade as one single app. Assuming you distribute your SDK to 100 apps, user giving OAuth grant to app 1 should not make app 2 auto get the grant).

But as long as you:

1. Ask your SDK consumers to register with Google:
   https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#get-config
2. Ask them to share with you their registered client ID for "Web
   Application" type and you can help them generate a config file your
   SDK is capable of reading.
3. In your Android SDK / module, you read the config file and use the client id when GoogleSignInOptions.Builder.requestIdToken(CLIENT_ID_FROM_CONFIG_FILE)
4. On your server, make sure to check ID token's 'audience' is one of
   the registered client IDs.

Then it should work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Isabella! Even I have gone through the latest blog post about the new sign in API in Android. We were facing this issue on May 16th and the blog post came on May 17th. But as soon as we got through the blog post, we implemented the exact same solution that you just briefed here. Marking your answer as accepted. :) Thanks.